# how to concat (_1) in string which is comma separeted in php?

Tags: php

this code is in php

```
 $v = 1,2,3,4,5;
```

as I have to concat `_1` in above variable

as I need this output  `$v = 1_1,2_1,3_1,4_1,5_1`

Comment: assuming this is array: explode it first, append your _1, then implode back to array

Comment: how bro can u show me

Comment: @vijaykumar try mine

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the PHP Manual:

- [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) — Join array elements with a string
- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) — Split a string by string

In your case:

```
$v = "1,2,3,4,5";
echo implode("_1,", explode(",", $v)) . "_1";
```

On a side note: since your string is a comma separated value, you might also be interested in

- [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) — Parse a CSV string into an array

Answer (score 1):

Without exploding/imploding, you can:

```
echo str_replace(',', '_1,', '1,2,3,4,5') . '_1';
```

Comment: This is probably faster than exploding/imploding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$v = "1,2,3,4,5;";
$newValue =  str_replace(",","_1,",$v);  //replace , with _1,
$newValue =  str_replace(";","_1;",$newValue); //replace ; with _1;
```

output:

1_1,2_1,3_1,4_1,5_1;

Comment: I dont think the ; is part of the string. The OP just forgot add the quotes in the question. Else it would be a syntax error.

Comment: @Gordon if that isn't just the first line will be enough to do what he wants to get done.

Answer (score 0):

Use array map

```
$v = '1,2,3,4,5';
$arr = explode(',',$v);
$arr = array_map(function ($val){
     return  $val.'_1';
},$arr);

echo implode(',',$arr);
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/IgzXWF#stdin)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put those numbers in quote.

```
$v = '1,2,3,4,5';

$new_v = explode(',', $v);

foreach ($new_v as $x) {
    $v1[] = $x.'_1';     
}
print_r($v1);
```

It will return array like this.

> Array ( [0] => 1_1 [1] => 2_1 [2] => 3_1 [3] => 4_1 [4] => 5_1 )